# How to handle merged cells and transpose the rows into columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such data in the excel file:
[image]

and I would like to format the structure of the data:

I want something like

[image]

What approaches can you recommend?

Comment: You can probably start by providing your input table (instead of a screenshot) so that others can easily help you. Check out the guide [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: There is a simple answer - don't ever use Merged Cells

Answer (score 1):

#### In Excel:

1. Manually unmerge merged cells
2. copy the range.
3. Paste special transpose.

[Link From Microsoft](http://%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BFhttps://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744)

[image: Page from Microsoft]

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm you could try something like this. Without the actual data to test it on, I cant confirm. It might be a solid start point though!

```
df = pd.read_excel(open('NAMEOFFILE.xlsx', 'rb')
df = df.transpose()
df.to_excel('NAMEOFFILE.xlsx', sheet_name='Transposed')
```

If you just needed to do it quickly in excel: Highlight all the data, copy it, then right click to paste where you want the data to be, and click "paste special", then finally "transpose"
[Click this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdZKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

df.T transposes the rows into columns in the dataframe

```
region=['Qtr1','Qtr2','Qtr3','Qtr4']
europe=[21704714,17987034,19485029,22567894]
asia=[8774099,12214447,14356879,15763492]
north_america=[12094215,10873099,15689543,17456723]

df=pd.DataFrame({'Region':region,'Europe':europe,'Asia':asia,'North    America':north_america})
types = pd.Series(data=['str', 'int', 'int', 'int'], index=['Region', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'North America'])
types = types.apply(eval)
df.reset_index()
df = df.astype(dtype=types.to_dict())
df=df.T
print(df.head())
```

use
xls=pd.read_excel(url,sheet_name=None) to retrieve your data into the dataframe